# Dual installation: Install windows 10 on dell latitude 3460 with factory pre-installed ubuntu

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, system-installation, windows, boot-partition

I recently got a dell latitude 3460 with ubuntu factory installed. I want to create a dual boot system and have taken all the necessary steps needed. I am now at a point where I am asked to select a partition to install windows. I created the appropriate partition and format prior to windows installation (in ubuntu) but can't access it during the installation of windows via USB boot device. Even though I have deleted and formatted the prepared partition, I can not gain access to it. Any ideas?